# IPSEC stack low speed

Tags: linux, linux-networking, linux-kernel, embedded-linux

I am working on Openswan IPSEC Implementation for Linux-kernel 2.6.35.9

My concern is when i do speed test using IPSEC kernel Images and without running IPSEC service i get speed of 40Mbps and 10Mbps.

while normally for kernel Images without IPSEC enabled in kernel i can see speed upto 88mbps.

why the speed is degraded just by enabling the IPSEC stack and not running the ipsec service.

Help me

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue with iptables modules when I tested Linux net performance. The performance decreased when the module where loaded. I think that Linux kernel module will handle traffic any time, when it is loaded( even if it has no configuration or rulls in my case).
Just try to check what modules are loaded,unload unneeded and check your performance again.
Also there may be a problem if those module precompiled into the kernel, so you need to recompile it with modules support.
Good luck.